# How to assign xelement as empty

Tags: sql, vb.net, xelement

I have a VB.net program that runs a query, fills a dataset and puts the information in a table.  I then email this table.  The program works, however I'd like to have the table fill different information if the dataset doesn't return any results.  My current code is:

```
Try
    Me.fTimeCardTableAdapter.Fill(Me.timecard.fTimeCard, "1/9/14", "1/10/14")
Catch ex As Exception
End Try

Dim Time1 = _
    <html>
      <body>
        <table border="1">
          <tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Total Hours</th><th>Break Time</th></tr>
            <%= From Time1break In Me.timecard.fTimeCard.AsEnumerable _
                    Select <tr><td><%= Time1break.sFirstName %></td>
                               <td><%= time1break.sLastName %>
                               </td><td><%= time1.TotalHours %></td>
                               <td><%= time1break.BreakTime %></td></tr> %>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
```

If the dataset is empty I want it to fill the table this way:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr><th>No Exceptions found</th></tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

I did try this:

```
Try
    Me.fTimeCardTableAdapter.Fill(Me.timecard.fTimeCard, "1/9/14", "1/10/14")
Catch ex As Exception
End Try

If (Me.timecard.fTimeCard.Count = 0) Then GoTo Line1 Else GoTo Line2

Line1:  Dim Time1 = _
            <html>
              <body>
                <table border="0">
                  <tr><th>No Break Exceptions For Yesterday</th></tr>
                </table>
              </body>
            </html>

Line2:
        Time1 = _
          <html>
            <body>
              <table border="1">
                <tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Total Hours</th><th>Break Time</th></tr>
                <%= From time1break In Me.timecard.fTimeCard.AsEnumerable _
                        Select <tr><td><%= Time1break.sFirstName %></td>
                                   <td><%= Time1break.sLastName %>
                                   </td><td><%= time1break.TotalHours %></td>
                                   <td><%= time1break.BreakTime %></td></tr> %>
              </table>
            </body>
          </html>
```

However, it still shows me "Line2" when the dataset is empty.

Comment: When you use `GoTo Line1` it will do both Line1 and Line2.  You shoudln't use GoTo.  Just put the code in the if then else statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
 Dim Time1
 If Not Me.timecard Is Nothing AndAlso (Me.timecard.Table(fTimeCard).Rows.Count <> 0) Then 
    Time1 = _
      <html>
        <body>
          <table border="1">
            <tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Total Hours</th><th>Break Time</th></tr>
            <%= From time1break In Me.timecard.fTimeCard.AsEnumerable _
                    Select <tr><td><%= Time1break.sFirstName %></td>
                               <td><%= Time1break.sLastName %>
                               </td><td><%= time1break.TotalHours %></td>
                               <td><%= time1break.BreakTime %></td></tr> %>
          </table>
        </body>
      </html>
 Else
     Time1 = _
        <html>
          <body>
            <table border="0">
              <tr><th>No Break Exceptions For Yesterday</th></tr>
            </table>
          </body>
        </html>
 End If
```

Comment: Is it dataset or datatable

Comment: me.timecard.ftimecard is a datatable.  me.timecard is the dataset

Comment: no dice.  it always goes to "Line2" which sends a blank table with the headers.  I tried switching "goto" line 1 and 2, Doesn't work.